# Does $A>B$ imply $A^B<B^A$?

Tags: inequality

Does $A>B$ imply $A^B<B^A$? A naive doubt, but I cannot find a proof. Does the property always hold true?

$A>B$ does not necessarily imply that $A^B<B^A$. How do we know if $A^B<B^A$ holds true or not? In other words, can we find $x$ such that for all $y$ with $x \leq y$, the inequality $x^y > y^x$  holds true?

Comment: I have formatted your post to make it look nicer and fix some (presumed) typos. Please make certain that I did not alter the intended meaning of your post.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Assuming $A>B>0$  $$A^B< B^A\iff A^{\frac1A}<B^{\frac1B}$$

Let $f(x)=x^{\frac1x}$

Can you check when $f(x)$ is increasing

Comment: @MayankJha, But this method does not come handy if one of $A<e<B$ To generalize Asaf Karagila's answer 
$$2^n \begin{cases}>n^2  &\mbox{if } n>4 \\
=n^2 & \mbox{if } n=4\\
<n^2  & \mbox{if } n<4 \end{cases}$$ as proved here(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497092/proof-by-induction-2n-n2-for-all-integer-n-greater-than-4)

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This answer was given to the [original version of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/520483/1).*

Not at all. Two examples:

$$2^4=4^2\\2^3<3^2$$

Comment: yeah. but in which cases does this hold true ?

Comment: Fix x. Then compare $x^a$ with $a^x$...

Comment: The Chaz, is there some quicker method wherein we can find some a such that for all y>=a the inequality pow(x,y)>pow(y,x) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is true as long as $A,B$ are large enough.  If you take logs, you are asking whether $A \gt B \implies B \log A \lt A \log B$ or $\frac B{\log B} \lt \frac A{\log A}$  Since $\log$ grows so slowly, this will be true whenever $A,B$ are reasonable size.  Taking the derivative of $\frac x{\log x}=\frac {\log x-1}{\log^2 x}$, which is positive for $x \gt e$, shows this will be true any time $A,B \gt e$