# Proof by induction: $3^n > n^2$ for all integers greater or equal to 1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

I have to prove that $3^n\geq n^2$ for all integers $n\geq1$ .

This task is quite similar to other like the one given in [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497092/proof-by-induction-2n-n2-for-all-integer-n-greater-than-4?newreg=f07124ef2b8e48ce9e6d2253129a3ef0), but with the difference that it has to be also valid for $n=1$. The usual approach uses $2n^2 > n^2 + 2n + 1$, which is just not true for $n=1$ as $n^2\ngeq 2n + 1$.

Are there any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: What do you have to prove? Your title says "$2^n>n^2$", but your question says "$3^n\geq n^2$".

Comment: Is your question for $2^n$ or $3^n$?

Comment: for $3^n$ - I adjusted the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$. Now start your induction for $n \geq 2$.

Above answer is for case $2^n$. For case $3^n$ we actually have $3^n>2^n$.