# Cant understand this inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction

This is from the question [proof by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497092/proof-by-induction-2n-n2-for-all-integer-n-greater-than-4?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This is for $ n \ge4 $

$$ 2^{n+1} = 2^n*2 > 2n^2 = n^2 + n^2 > n^2 + 2n + 1 = (n + 1)^2 $$

$$2^{n+1}>(n + 1)^2$$

The part that I can't understand is how they got this part $$ n^2 + n^2 > n^2 + 2n + 1$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proving the step $n^2+n^2\geq n^2+2n+1$

$$\begin{array}{rl|r}n^2+n^2&= n^2+n\cdot n&\text{by properties of exponents}\\
&> n^2 +3n&\text{since}~n>3\\
&=n^2+2n+n&\text{by properties of addition}\\
&>n^2+2n+1&\text{since}~n>1\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I just have one question, how come we're allowed to use the fact $n>1$ if we put the limitation that the inequality holds only for all integer n greater than 3?

Comment: $n>3$ and $3>1$ together imply that $n>1$ is true as well.  Any conclusion that follows from hypotheses can further be used later in the proof to prove something else.  This is despite that the inequality $n>1$ is not strict, it is still a useful inequality for us here and is enough to imply what we want for that particular step.

Answer (score 0):

It amounts to $n^2>2n+1\iff n(n-2)>1$, and as $n-2\ge 2$...

Answer (score 0):

Subtract $n^2+2n+1$ from both sides to get $n^2-2n-1>0$. Solve the inequality for $n$. You should find that for $n>4$, The inequality is true.

Answer (score 0):

We know this is true for a value of $n$. We must now prove it for $n+1$

\begin{align}
2^{n+1} &\gt (n+1)^2 &\qquad\text{This is what we want to prove}\\
2^{n+1} &= 2^n \cdot2 &\qquad\text{This is true for all n}\\
2^n &> n^2 &\qquad\text{This is true by induction}\\
2^n \cdot 2&> 2n^2 &\qquad\text{Multiplication}\\
2^n \cdot 2&> n^2 + n^2 &\qquad\text{Just splitting it up}\\
n^2 + n^2 &> n^2 + 2n + 1&\qquad\text{We're trying to get to the first formula }\\
n^2 &\gt 2n+1  &\quad\text{True for all values of $n$ that satisfy the original induction}\\
n^2 + n^2 &> (n+1)^2 &\qquad\text{And now we simplify}\\
\end{align}
$$2^{n+1} \gt 2n^2 \gt (n+1)^2$$

Comment: We are trying to get the first formula, so we want to manipulate one side to give us $(n+1)^2$. Clearly, we can't get to it from an exponential equation, so we switch to comparing the two quadratics. The formula in itself is obviously true for $n \gt 3$, so it will work for all the $n$ we pick. The key is to realize that getting this inequality will help us get the first inequality that I have.